# Align Drawable right for Button issue?

Tags: android, image, button

Hi I have button in my layout,for the button am setting image as drawable right its working fine in hdpi,xhdpi(i.e in nexus 4,samsung S III) but not in Nexus 7.I know it will use tvdpi if no folder found named tvdpi then will use hdpi.I used code for my button is as below

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/my_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/image"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</button>
```

My issues is its showing images completely inside button but need should touch right,top and bottom of my button.Please guide me .Thanks in advance

Comment: can you put a screenshot if possible?

Comment: you are welcome @sugan s

Comment: who removed the answer?